# Javascript breaking a page in Firefox 3.6

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I'm using the [jCarousel Lite jQuery plugin](http://www.gmarwaha.com/blog/2007/08/09/jcarousel-lite-a-jquery-plugin/) on a page, but it seems to be causing severe problems in Firefox 3.6. In that browser, the page briefly loads, and then all of the content disappears, except for one of the `<li>` elements that I'm using the plugin on.

The page in question is [here](http://oggdev.brightagency.net/). The code applying the carousel:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(window).load(function() {
        jQuery(".loopnetcarousel").jCarouselLite({
            btnNext: ".next",
            btnPrev: ".prev"
        });
    });

</script>
```

(I was initially using `(document).ready`, but replaced that with `(window).load` after seeing that some people have problems with it in Firefox 3.6, but that didn't seem to change anything).

More information: If I stop the page load before all of the page content is replaced as described, everything works fine, including the carousel. Also, I tried replacing that carousel script with another one, and the same problem occurs.

Comment: What does the Firebug error console tell you?

Comment: The page appears to continually be loading, and in the console (but in the info tab, not the error tab) it says "Reload to activate window console".

Comment: If Firebug says "Reload", you opened and enabled Firebug for the site after it was loaded, so you just have to do what it says and reload the page with Firebug enabled. If you don't figure out the problem, see if you can create a minimal test case on http://jsfiddle.net/.

Comment: I have reloaded the page, but unfortunately it still gives that message, even after a reload.

Comment: Are you using other jquery js including jCarousel Lite jQuery plugin ??

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but there are other plugins that utilize jQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the problem is the way that the loopnet.com properties are loaded. The loopnet.com scripts use document.write to create the carousel content. If you look at the Net tab in Firebug you will see that the loopnet.com scripts are all loaded twice. First when the page loads and then again when the carousel script is run. The second time it is run in Firefox the document.write just clears the entire page. A simple fix would be to just remove the script tags before setting up the carousel code. Example jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fqFH7/7/

```
 $(function() {
    //remove the scripts so that they are not executed again by the carousel code
    jQuery(".loopnetcarousel script").remove();    

    jQuery(".loopnetcarousel").jCarouselLite({
        btnNext: ".next",
        btnPrev: ".prev"
    });
});
```

Try commenting out the remove() line in the jsFiddle and you will see the same problem as your site.

Answer (score 0):

On the page you refer to, the following resource takes forever to load:

> http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/opensans/v5/cJZKeOuBrn4kERxqtaUH3bO3LdcAZYWl9Si6vvxL-qU.woff

Comment: I removed that from the page, but the error still exists with Firefox 3.6.

Answer (score 0):

On the website for the plugin:

> Based on popular request, jCarouselLite has been updated to support jquery 1.2.x versions. Goto the download page and download version 1.0.1 to enjoy jquery 1.2.x support. Since  Firefox 3 has some issues with $(document).ready() function, try using $(window).load() instead if you face any problems. Hopefully a future version of Firefox or jQuery will fix the problem.

Taken from: http://www.gmarwaha.com/blog/2007/08/09/jcarousel-lite-a-jquery-plugin/